# how to get the value of last td in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

i am try to get last tr and then last td

```
  var lastimageId = $("#GVUserWebDetail tr:last").children("td:first").html();
```

but null is return

please give any solution

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET grid view? Please mention

Answer (score 0):

> i am try to get **last** tr and then **last** td

If you're trying to get the last row and cell, how about this:

```
$(function()
{
    var bottomRightCell = $("#GVUserWebDetail tr:last-child td:last-child");

    var message = 'id: ' + bottomRightCell.attr('id') + '\n';
    message += 'text: ' + bottomRightCell.text();

    alert(message);
});​
```

### [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/HwvhW/1/)

Comment: object Object alert appear not value of last td

Comment: That's correct, it *is* an object, more specifically a jQuery object. What information are you trying to access?

Comment: `var bottomRightCellId = bottomRightCell.attr('id');`

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle demonstration for clarity. It does work. :)